# Login timeout Azure linked server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I want to query a supplier Azure SQL PDWH from our on-premises server (SQL 2014) to extract data from that Azure SQL PDWH and insert into a database that is located on the on-premises server. In the end this should automated via stored procedures that reside in the on-premises database and are scheduled.

To do so I have setup a linked server between the Azure SQL DWH and our on-premises server using the following scripts that I found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure/

```
/*
Create new linked server
*/

-- Make a link to the cloud
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'read_only_dwhs', 
   @srvproduct=N'Azure SQL Db',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc=N'server.database.windows.net,1433',
   @catalog='xxxxxx';
GO

--Set up login mapping
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
   @rmtsrvname = 'read_only_dwhs', 
   @useself = 'FALSE', 
   @locallogin=NULL,
   @rmtuser = 'xxxxxx',
   @rmtpassword = 'xxxxxx'
GO
```

These statements run without errors. However, when I execute the *sp_testlinkedserver* it returns a time-out error after about 10 seconds.

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "read_only_dwhs" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "read_only_dwhs" returned message "Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response".
>
> Msg 258, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
> TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].

I checked with IT and they confirm that nothing is blocked by the firewall relating this and that TCP/IP is enabled. Our supplier also confirms that our IP is added to the Azure Firewall. I have no problem querying direct from the Azure SQL PDWH database via visual studio community 2015.

Also tools like these: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ give the same error on connecting.

I searched for hours, but whatever I do it keeps returning the same error message.

Any help is appreciated.

Update 2016 09 27:

After some more testing with IT it seems like this has to do with our firewall settings.

When I directly query via the database from the on-premises server (connected via remote desktop) to the Azure DWH I get no errors and everything works. I am than also able to query from my local machine, using the same on-premises database.

However, when another colleague logs on to the on-premises server I am not able anymore to query from my local machine (with the time-out errors above) until I login again to the (on-premises) server with my credentials.

I think that the firewall rule is too strict in only allowing information to be sent/received to the Azure DWH if my credentials are active on the on-premises server.

Update 2016 09 28:
The issue seems to be fixed for now. IT managed to apply the correct settings to the firewall. The server can now communicate with the Azure DWH even when colleagues are logged on to the server.

This might help some-one else.

Comment: Were the firewall updates added to the Azure SQL Server, or an on-premise firewall?